# iOS web app exiting full screen from iframe link

Tags: jquery, ios, web-applications

I have an iframe inside my ios fullscreen web app, the iframe source is a map from batchgeo.com. I added a html link to pass data from the map to the app (e.g. example.com?name=bob), it reloads the same page but with the data. But when the link is clicked on it exits the app and opens the link in Safari, I would like it to open in the full screen app and not go to safari.

I tried something like `<a target="_parent" href="http://example.com?name=bob">` with no luck. I also tried changing the default behaviour of the link with jquery in the web app, but that doesn't want to work with this code I found from another similar question but that doesn't work for the link inside the iframe:

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {

$(document).on(
"click",
"a",
function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var aurl = $(event.target).attr("href");
    if (aurl) {
        location.href = $(event.target).attr("href");
    }
    else {
        location.href = this;
    }
}
);
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you happen to solve this issue? I've got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple to do :

```
$('a').on('click touchend', function(ev){

    $(this).preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');

});
```

Comment: had not thought of the touch event, but didn't work anyway, not even for links in the app let alone in the iframe.